# Why is an Arduino program called a sketch?

Tags: arduino, terminology

I've recently began Arduino development, and while explaining it to friends and co-workers, one of the questions I've received that I have no answer for and also would like to know is why is the program the microcontroller runs called a sketch? Is this a convention carried over from electrical engineering? I'm not familiar with the history of this particular term.

Comment: a sketch term is more meaningful to an artist than a developer - it's something quick'n'dirty to play with/explore/learn and potentially the start of something interesting. Arduino and Processing is aimed at teaching computing literacy in the arts/design so terminology also helps coat sugar on a dull/scary subject for creatives I guess. "Sketch" does sound more encouraging/appealing than "GCC C++ Executable/Arduino Due/X - ATSAM3X8E" for example :)

Comment: And while we're at it, why is an add-on circuit board a "shield"?

Comment: 'These boards are called “shields,” because they usually fit over the top of Arduino like a protecting shield.' - [Environmental Monitoring with Arduino](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/-/9781449328603/new-component-ethernet-shield/chapter_6)

Comment: @Alan - thanks. Sigh. Bad metaphor.

Comment: There is nothing as the Arduino programming language. It is plain old C++ without exception and RTTI. Just look at the compiler which is used : avr-g++

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Arduino programming language is based on Processing, which is aimed at visual artists. Hence a development version being a 'sketch'.

"Processing is a programming language, development environment, and online community that since 2001 has promoted software literacy within the visual arts. Initially created to serve as a software sketchbook and to teach fundamentals of computer programming within a visual context, Processing quickly developed into a tool for creating finished professional work as well."

- [processing.org/about](http://www.processing.org/about/)

Comment: Perfect, thanks. It was making little to no sense, and now it does!

Answer (score 0):

That's a good question. You would be best to Google `'Processing'` as that is the language and IDE that the Arduino borrows for constructing programmes. I'm guessing the name is abritrary, although it links in with the manner in which Arduino programmes are 'sketched' out and then improved upon.